# Module parse fails for .jpg in <img> for React component?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I want to show an image on my website I'm building using react. Here is the component source code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import style from './styles/AboutMeStyle.css';

export default class AboutMe extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <img src={require ('./images/ProfilePic.jpg')}align="middle"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The file seems to be found but I keep getting an exception stating that the module parse failed...? Here is a text output of the error from the terminal:

```
Module parse failed: /Users/megan/Desktop/Personal Website/client/components/images/ProfilePic.jpg
Unexpected character (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character (1:0)
...
```

Am I writing the code wrong? Or am I missing a module? I've installed image-webpack-loader but it didn't seem to do anything...Here is my webpack.config.js :

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './client/index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public/js',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    stats: {
        colors: true,
        reasons: true
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loaders: ['babel']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please replace the image with the actual error message. It'll help make this question more searchable.

Comment: Done. Replaced the image with text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` is used to import javascript code. You probably want something like:

```
<img src="/images/ProfilePic.jpg" align="middle"/>
```

which would read from your public images folder. Looking more closely at your terminal I see you have your images inside the `components` folder. Usually you want to have some images / other assets folder inside a public directory apart from your javascript components.

Webpack will compile all the code into a bundle, and your webserver will expose the public files under the root directory.

See [webpack publicPath config options](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath) for more info.

Comment: Thanks! Moving the image to the /public/images folder worked!